# Unexpected T Variable_ PHP mail form

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm trying to set up a PHP mail form, and I've never done so. When I test my form, I get

> 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /nfs/raven/u1/t/tannav/public_html/mail.php on line 8'

This is what my PHP file looks like, I haven't yet gotten around to adding captcha.

```
<?PHP
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = 'tannav@onid.oregonstate.edu';
$subject = "Contact Form"
$mailheader = 'From: $email'. '\r\n';
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error")
?>
```

Comment: heads up: Your code is vulnerable to header injection

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a semicolon (`;`) after `$subject = "Contact Form"`. The next symbol PHP encounters is `$mailheader`, which can't just follow a string literal - hence the error. To fix it, just add the missing semicolon:

```
<?PHP
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent=" From: $name \n Message: $message";
$recipient = 'tannav@onid.oregonstate.edu';
$subject = "Contact Form"; // Note the ";" added here.
$mailheader = 'From: $email'. '\r\n';
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error")
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a `;` after `$subject = "Contact Form"` on line7